# How to use ogr2ogr to download WFS data congaining special characters (such as \x01)?

Tags: python, ogr2ogr, mapserver, xml, gml

**Problem**

I am interested in the `ms:C_GAZ` layer of [this WFS endpoint](https://georisques.gouv.fr/services?language=fre&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0). QGIS can connect to this the endpoint and visualise its data without any error (I recommend zooming in heavily to a big city to avoid trying to load the whole dataset). I would like to download the data to a GPKG file. I do:

```
URL="https://georisques.gouv.fr/services?language=fre&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0"
ogr2ogr test.gpkg WFS:$URL ms:C_GAZ
```

However, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1: XML parsing of GML file failed : not well-formed (invalid token) at line 2101, column 79
ERROR 1: XML parsing of GML file failed : not well-formed (invalid token) at line 38, column 79
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer ms:C_GAZ (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_insert_feature_count_ms:C_GAZ" AFTER INSERT ON "ms:C_GAZ" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents SET feature_count = feature_count + 1 WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('ms:C_GAZ'); END;) failed: no such table: main.ms:C_GAZ
ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TRIGGER "trigger_delete_feature_count_ms:C_GAZ" AFTER DELETE ON "ms:C_GAZ" BEGIN UPDATE gpkg_ogr_contents SET feature_count = feature_count - 1 WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('ms:C_GAZ'); END;) failed: no such table: main.ms:C_GAZ
```

---

**One possible solution**

Instead of [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html), I download the data with `curl`:

```
curl "https://georisques.gouv.fr/services?language=fre&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ms:C_GAZ&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=80000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" \
    -o test.resp
```

I try parsing it with Python:

```
import xmltodict
with open('test.resp') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExpatError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [42], line 3
      1 import xmltodict
      2 with open('test.resp') as fd:
----> 3     doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

File ~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/gleam-3xfTBcJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xmltodict.py:378, in parse(xml_input, encoding, expat, process_namespaces, namespace_separator, disable_entities, process_comments, **kwargs)
    376     parser.Parse(b'',True)
    377 else:
--> 378     parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
    379 return handler.item

ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 248926, column 79
```

Instead of parsing, let's just read in the file:

```
with open("test.resp") as f:
    d = f.readlines()
```

Inspect the line `xmltodict` is complaining about:

[image]

There is a strange character, `\x01`. The `xmltodict` error mentions column 79. `d[248925][79]` returns: `'\x01'`. Let's remove all instances of `'\x01'`:

```
lines = [re.sub(r'\x01', '', each) for each in d]
```

Write new file, without `'\x01'`s:

```
with open("test.resp.filtered","w") as f:
    for l in lines:
        f.write(l)
```

Try reading new file in with `xmltodict`:

```
import xmltodict
with open('test.resp.filtered') as f:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(f.read())
```

Works. Now try converting result to GPKG:

```
ogr2ogr test.gpkg test.resp.filtered
```

Also works: `test.gpkg` can now be opened in QGIS.

---

**Question**

The above presented solution works, but it is rather tedious. It involves me manually inspecting the file, writing code which replaces the misbehaving characters. On the other hand, QGIS has no problem processing the data sent by the WFS endpoint. I would like to use `ogr2ogr` with similar levels of ease. Something like:

```
URL="https://georisques.gouv.fr/services?language=fre&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0"
ogr2ogr test.gpkg WFS:$URL ms:C_GAZ --config WHAT_COMES_HERE?
```

would make processing such files much easier.

**How can I download data with such special characters to a GPKG file from a WFS endpoint?**

Comment: I would contact georisques.gouv.fr and ask them to fix their data.

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion, thanks. The issue with it, is that this above, or similar errors occur very frequently in French government-related WFS services, and I think they are unlikely to fix them anytime soon.

Comment: if no one tells them they are breaking things then it will never get fixed

Comment: We are telling them, don't worry :)

Comment: I removed the geopackage tag and added a mapserver tag because the server out there seems to be Mapserver. I think it should not generate invalid XML. The problem is that the XML version is 1.0 and character  x01 is a valid UTF-8 character but not allowed within XML documents. Maybe the XML writer of Mapserver could sanitize the output.